# symfony annotations access to another field

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I wanna have a start date and end date field in the database, but start date cant be greater than end date (logically) but is there any way to use Entity to make a comparison (with Assert/Constraints) or I have to do it elsewhere(and where)

in this example I use

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 * @Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual("today")
 */
private $start_date;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */
private $end_date;
```

is it possible at $end date to have @Assert\GreaterThan($start_date) somehow

can I access that or I need to have some custom function for that kind of check, and what is best practice to create that kind of check in Symfony

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement a class constraint validator for your entity. In that validator your can get the whole entity as an argument and then you can compare the dates like this:

```
if ($value->getStartDate() > $value->getEndDate()) {
     $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
            ->atPath('startDate')
            ->addViolation();
}
```

Look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator